# Put Progress Load on the jquery Autocomplete plugin in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to put a progress bar in textboxes that use the autocomplete plugin.To call all the information from the database this progress bar will be show.Like what you see in the picture

[image]

See my current picture and please guide me.

[image]

```
    <div class="col-md-6 ">

<label>شغل بیمه
        
    <span style="color:red;margin-top:2px" >*</span>
        </label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="SematYaShoghlBime"  asp-for="@Model.person.SematYaShoghlBime"  placeholder="جستجو کنید...">
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SematYaShoghlBime").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON("/Home/SearchInTaminJobs", {
                    term: $("#SematYaShoghlBime").val().trim()

                },
                    response)
            },
            minLength:7,
        });
    });
</script>

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SearchInTaminJobs()
{
    string term = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();
    var query = _context.TaminJobs.Where(Ad => Ad.jobName.Contains(term)).Select(c => c.jobName + c.jobCode).ToList();

        return Ok(query);
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo you could follow:

```
<input type="text" id="SematYaShoghlBime">
<img id="loading" style="display:none;width:30px;height:30px" src="https://bodhitreeyogaresort.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/loading_icon_sm.gif" />
@section Scripts{
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#SematYaShoghlBime").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $("#loading").show();
                    $.getJSON("/Home/SearchInTaminJobs", {
                        term: $("#SematYaShoghlBime").val().trim()

                    }, function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (el, index) {
                            return el;
                        }));
                        $("#loading").hide();
                    })
                },              
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Rena Would you please answer this question too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728652/put-scroll-down-for-results-in-jquery-autocomplete-plugin-in-asp-net-core?noredirect=1#comment121470012_68728652

Comment: Hi @sadeghfarest, try to add this css style: `.ui-autocomplete { max-height: 100px;  /* or using height:100px; */   overflow-y: auto;     /* prevent horizontal scrollbar */ 
   overflow-x: hidden;     /* add padding to account for vertical scrollbar */     padding-right: 20px;}`