# Put Scroll down for results in jquery Autocomplete plugin in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to put Scroll down for results that use the autocomplete plugin.
I may have more than 1000 results, so I want a scroll bar to scroll through the results
like this picture

[image]

I think putting an input in the combo box. Please help mel

See my current picture and please guide me.

[image]

```
<label>شغل بیمه
        
    <span style="color:red;margin-top:2px" >*</span>
        </label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="SematYaShoghlBime"  asp-for="@Model.person.SematYaShoghlBime"  placeholder="جستجو کنید...">


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SematYaShoghlBime").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON("/Home/SearchInTaminJobs", {
                    term: $("#SematYaShoghlBime").val().trim()

                },
                    response)
            },
            minLength:7,
        });
    });
</script>

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult SearchInTaminJobs()
{
    string term = HttpContext.Request.Query["term"].ToString();
    var query = _context.TaminJobs.Where(Ad => Ad.jobName.Contains(term)).Select(c => c.jobName + c.jobCode).ToList();

        return Ok(query);
 
}
```

Comment: If you have that many results I'd consider how useful that is as an auto-complete... (limit your results to the most useful)...   for scrollbar see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102832/ul-or-div-vertical-scrollbar/4102846

Answer (score 1):

I used custom data here, you can use Selectize Js, the effect is as follows.

View:

```
@{ Layout = null;}
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var country = ["Australia", "Bangladesh", "Denmark", "Hong Kong", "Indonesia", "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "South Africa"];
            $("#country").select2({
                data: country
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>DropDown with Search using jQuery</h1>
    <div>
        <select id="country" style="width:300px;">
            <!-- Dropdown List Option -->
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:
[image]

use autocomplete:

```
@{ Layout = null;}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Autocomplete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//apps.bdimg.com/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script src="//apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//apps.bdimg.com/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqueryui/style.css">
    <style>
        .ui-autocomplete {
            max-height: 100px;
            overflow-y: auto;
           
            overflow-x: hidden;
           
        }
        * html .ui-autocomplete {
            height: 100px;
          
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
                "ActionScript",
                "AppleScript",
                "Asp",
                "BASIC",
                "C",
                "C++",
                "Clojure",
                "COBOL",
                "ColdFusion",
                "Erlang",
                "Fortran",
                "Groovy",
                "Haskell",
                "Java",
                "JavaScript",
                "Lisp",
                "Perl",
                "PHP",
                "Python",
                "Ruby",
                "Scala",
                "Scheme"
            ];
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags,
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <label for="tags" style="color:cornflowerblue">title：</label>
            <input id="tags" >
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to put Scroll down for results that use the autocomplete plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my code. Does it meet your needs now?